# Concept of infinity in limits

Tags: definition, mathematics, singularities

Can somebody explain as to what is difference between an expression being undefined ( such as 0/0) and one being an an infinity?

Comment: This is a mathematics question, not physics. And 0/0 isn't exactly undefined, per se. Technically, it's an indeterminate form. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form

Comment: Actually I as solving limits in kinematics and came across this. I know this is mathematics but at that time I had physics in my mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could think of it like this:

- Impossible results/numbers/values in mathematics are termed *undefined*.

In physics such undefined results appear for different reasons, maybe because a number reaches (goes towards) infinity or maybe because a number (or group/set/amount) is empty / non-existing.

The mathematical term *undefined* can therefore have different physical meanings. In the specific case of dividing with zero, $5/0$, we are talking about a value reaching infinity physically speaking.

Since math is our tool or "language" with which we work in physics, such undefined values must be investigated as *limits* or alike since direct calculation is mathematically impossible. To evaluate what $5/0$ means, one would instead say $5/x$ and then let $x$ come closer and closer to $0$:
The "trend" in the values when this is done, tells us what the value "would be", had it been possible (so to speak). Usually, mathematically written as:

$$5/x\rightarrow\infty\quad \text{for}\quad x\rightarrow 0$$

In the extra special case of both deviding with zero *and* multiplying with zero, $0/0$, you physically can't evaluate this as infinite, because although the denominator causes the trend towards infinity, the numerator causes an equally dominant trend towards zero. This may be a physical case of an empty set (simply, non-existing results - not infinite values, but **non-existing** values). Look at how this calculation has appeared physically, and that should be clear.

Comment: I think mathematicians would write it as $\lim_{x\to0^+}5x^{-1}\to\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to0^-}5x^{-1}\to-\infty$, which indicates that the limit does *not* exist.